# Customizing Strapi field labels

Tags: strapi

I have a strapi model representing a collection, specified by the below JSON:

```
{
  "kind": "collectionType",
  "collectionName": "orgs",
  "info": {
    "name": "Organization",
    "description": ""
  },
  "options": {
    "increments": true,
    "timestamps": true,
    "draftAndPublish": false
  },
  "attributes": {
    "backToTopButton": {
      "type": "BackToTopButton",
      "columnType": "object"
    },
    "relationNavigation": {
      "type": "RelationNavigation",
      "columnType": "object",
      "entityUid": "communities",
      "selectedIndex": 0,
      "items": [
        {
          "relationEntityUid": "orgs",
          "label": "Information",
          "value": "Community",
          "localKey": "communityId",
          "foreignKey": "communityId",
          "relationType": "OneToOne"
        },
        {
          "relationEntityUid": "Connectorsetting",
          "label": "",
          "value": "Connectors",
          "localKey": "communityId",
          "foreignKey": "communityId",
          "relationType": "OneToOne"
        }
      ]
    },
    "yglId": {
      "type": "number"
    },
    "name": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "segmentType": {
      "type": "DropDown",
      "columnType": "string",
      "stretchType": "half",
      "cssOverride": false,
      "options": ["Strategic 1", "Strategic 2", "Strategic 3", "SBAM", "Self Serve"]
    },
    "reportingSuite": {
      "type": "DropDown",
      "columnType": "string",
      "options": ["Strategic A", "Strategic B", "Strategic C", "Strategic D", "Strategic E", "Strategic F", "Strategic G", "Strategic H", "Strategic I", "Strategic J", "SBAM", "SBAM A", "SBAM B", "SBAM C"]
    }
  }
}
```

I have to have custom labels, for example, for the attribute - `segmentType` I would love to be able to write `"organization segment"`.

Ideally, I am looking for a way to rewrite this similar to:

```
"segmentType": {
  "type": "DropDown",
  "columnType": "string",
  "stretchType": "half",
  "cssOverride": false,
  "options": ["Strategic 1", "Strategic 2", "Strategic 3", "SBAM", "Self Serve"],
  "label": "organization segment"
},
```

I could not find any examples of how to do this without coding [a plugin], using just the JSON.

Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this through the View Configuration interface.
To get to this interface, just go to the Collection/Single type then click the “Configure the view” button.
See this [Screenshot for Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fi4tK.jpg)

When you are in the View Configuration interface,  click the pencil icon on the field with which you want to edit the Label.
See this [Screenshot for Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qSEd.jpg)